# Intersection of a vector in the interpolation line between two vectors? Reverse Linear Interpolation?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, intersection

Check the image [image: pic]

Basically I have a vector direction (c) that sits between two vectors (a and b) and I want to find P the point of intersection of the direction of c with the line defined by a and b.

So I have all three vectors in a plane, and want to find P.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up intersection of two lines?

Comment: Yes I do sir, but it's visual programing... nodes.
as in this image: http://prntscr.com/6reyfc

My failed attempt consisted of having the angle between A and C be divided by the angle between A and B so I could have a factor for linear interpolation. But it's not working as you can see. I guess it's not the same as calculating the difference between angles, but something else I should be using to get the factor for the LERP between A and B to get the intersection. Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: It's solved.... close it at will. And it is about programming... I wanted a step of instructions to feed my 3D software to solve this. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector *OP* is `P = (1-t)*A+t*B` and you need to find `P` such that `C×P=0` where `×` is the vector cross product. In the end I get

```
t = (ax*cy-ay*cx)/(ax*cy-ay*cx-bx*cy+by*cx)
px = cx*(ax*by-ay*bx)/(ax*cy-ay*cx-bx*cy+by*cx)
py = cy*(ax*by-ay*bx)/(ax*cy-ay*cx-bx*cy+by*cx)
```

Example, `A=(1,6)`, `B=(5,2)`, `C=(0.5,0.8)`

```
t = 11/26
px = 35/13
py = 56/13
```

Check results with GeoGebra:

[image: pic]

Comment: yeah, my problem is definitely finding t. I would like to know if the t, px and py formulas are a deconstruction of commonly known operations, since I operate with nodes and instead of have each calculus step, maybe I have a construct that does sections of it. To me looks like if random, meaning, I'm not understanding its meaning from a higher position but I can definitely apply those steps. Thanks

Comment: basically I want to find t so I can interpolate 3D space vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved this one in a way that was computable to my brain.

Image description, as I'm a visual person: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0qWX.png

projected one of the vector to the edge and subtracted the projection to that one of the vector, that' gives me p, a perpendicular vector to the edge.

Then projected c onto p and whatever was the factor of that projection length with the length of p I multiplied c with, giving me the point of intersection.

Sorry if this a very wonky implementation, but the output on my end is just what I needed.